# Stack overflow when setting variable

Tags: c#, mef

I am writing a program using the MEF framework to create plugins. When trying to set a variable in one of the plugins, I am getting a stack overflow exception.

the variable in the plugin is defined as `public string bnick {get {return bnick;} set {bnick = value;}}`

the calling code in the main program:

```
 public void SetUpPlugins()
        {
        foreach (Plugin p in plugins)
            {
            p.bnick = nick;
            p.HostProgram = this;
            }
        }
```

Using the debugger I determined that the line `p.bnick = nick` is only getting called once. And it never gets to the next line.

Why is this filling up the stack and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public string bnick {get {return bnick;} set {bnick = value;}}
```

Here, you are assigning `bnick` in the body of the setter again, creating a stack overflow. Did you intend to create an instance Variable instead, something like

```
private string bnick = "";
public string Bnick 
{
  get 
  { 
   return bnick;
  } 
  set 
  { 
    bnick = value;
  }
}
```

Note: in C#, the convention is to write properties in PascalCase.

Comment: Thanks, I hate making simple mistakes like this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your getter and setter are calling themselves recursively. Try this:

```
private string _bnick;
public string bnick 
{ 
    get { return this._bnick; }
    set { this._bnick = value; }
}
```

Or more simply, use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) to avoid this kind of problem:

```
public string bnick { get; set; }
```

As *Femaref* points out, to follow C#'s coding guidelines, it should look like this:

```
public string Bnick { get; set; }
```

Comment: why is that worth a +1? It's not needed to denote the member variables due to using an IDE, and also, it's against the style guides of C#.

Comment: @Femaref  Because it's clearer. I like to CTRL + scroll my way around code, not use the mouse excessively. And also, link and then I will trust you.

Comment: The guidelines say that properties should be PascalCase, and then the backing fields can either be camelCase, or else just omitted by using an auto-property.

Comment: @Femaref you're right of course (+1 btw). I wouldn't write it this way in my own code unless for some reason I absolutely *had* to. I simply proposed this as the minimum amount of change necessary to solve OP's problem (renaming the public property would require updating all references)

Comment: @p.s.w.g: wasn't critizing you - I was critizing the underscore being a reason for a upvote (not that it is a reason to downvote either).